# Count of Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (SQL Server)

```
      Date     |    Time          |  Id      |  Patient
   -------------------------------------------------------
    2018-06-19 | 18:02:49.0000000 | 1800257  |  Patient1
    2018-06-19 | 18:04:24.0000000 | 1800258  |  Patient2
    2018-06-19 | 18:35:35.0000000 | 1800259  |  Patient3
```

How to get Count of Same Date with in Same Query

I have to try this

```
select COUNT(con.AppDate) as Appointment,con.AppDate as Date 
from Consultation as con 
inner join DoctorMaster as doc on con.DrCode=doc.id 
where con.DrCode='2'      
GROUP BY CAST(AppDate AS DATE),con.AppDate
```

Use this i am getting only count of date  but i want one more column that is time which is use for scheduling

**Expected Output:**

```
 CountOfDate  |     Date     |     Time     |  Patient
----------------------------------------------------------
    3         |   2018-06-19 |   18:02:49   |  Patient1
    3         |   2018-06-19 |   19:10:10   |  Patient1
    3         |   2018-06-19 |   19:02:50   |  Patient1
```

How to show Count of date each row ?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would really helpful .

Comment: I don't understand why the time `18:02:49` is repeated three times in the output.  But, besides this, why are you storing date and time separately in the first place?  This is generally something which may lead to problems.

Comment: do you have separate date and time column or only single datetime column AppDate ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  ya actually i am working on scheduling i want to show count of  Appointment on monthly basis and when select date show total count of date with timing

Comment: @Squirrel yes i have a separate date and  time  column AppDate, AppTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per sample data you seems want:

```
select *, count(*) over (partition by date) as CountOfDate, 
          min(Patient) over (partition by date) as Patient
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question and sample data, I guess you need to `select`  `CAST(con.AppDate AS DATE)` instead of  `con.AppDate`.

```
select COUNT(con.AppDate) as Appointment,CAST(con.AppDate AS DATE) as Date 
from  Consultation as con 
inner join DoctorMaster as doc on con.DrCode=doc.id   
where con.DrCode='2'
```

**EDIT**

I saw you edit your question

You can try to use `COUNT` with windows function, and `CAST(t.Time AS time(0))` let time format to `hh:mm:ss`

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY con.AppDate ORDER BY con.AppDate) CountOfDate,
        con.AppDate,
        CAST(con.AppTime AS time(0)) time,
        con.Patient
from Consultation as con inner join DoctorMaster as doc on con.DrCode=doc.id   
where con.DrCode='2'
```

**[Results]**:

```
| CountOfDate |    AppDate |     time |  Patient |
|-------------|------------|----------|----------|
|           3 | 2018-06-19 | 18:02:49 | Patient1 |
|           3 | 2018-06-19 | 18:04:24 | Patient2 |
|           3 | 2018-06-19 | 18:35:35 | Patient3 |
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2feac/1

Answer (score 1):

you can use window function COUNT() OVER ()

```
select COUNT(con.AppDate) OVER (PARTITION BY con.DrCode, con.AppDate) as Appointment,
       con.AppDate as Date,
       con.AppTime as Time 
from   Consultation as con 
       inner join DoctorMaster as doc 
       on con.DrCode = doc.id   
where  con.DrCode = '2'
```